# How to make input size bigger?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yui-pure-css

Here is the demo for it - http://plnkr.co/edit/B2lPwBgY61fSzg4nbaeD?p=preview

I am using both [Twitter Bootstrap forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) and [Pure Forms](http://purecss.io/forms/) and as you can see in demo, the size of input box is very small.

I even tried to increase the size by overriding as follows

```
.pure-form .input-medium {
  size: 50px;
}
```

But it doesn't helps

How can I make size of input text box **bigger**?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size` isn't a CSS property, it's an HTML attribute. You want `width` (or `height`) in a CSS context to adjust the size of the element.